# Google Chrome and Firefox not loading any pages graphics card issue

Tags: nvidia, firefox, google-chrome, intel-graphics, browser

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox stopped working after a `sudo apt upgrade`. They won't even open the settings page. My internet connect is good and I'm able to connect with other applications.

I seems to be a graphics card issue.

When running Chrome form the command line I get the error message below when using the NVIDIA graphics card:

```
gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported chrome ubuntu
```

After changing to Intel the erro message is the following:

```
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
```

A fresh installation of Chromium is working just fine.

I already tried purging and re-installing both without any success.

Comment: UPDATE: Both started working again after another update. Still couldn't figure it out what caused it, but seems to be resolved in Chrome 108.0.5359.94 and Mozilla Firefox 107.0.1. I still get some graphic glitches with Chrome, however.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- uninstalling,
- removing the user cache and config directories (~/.config/google-chrome and ~/.config/google-chrome) - this assumes you have nothing local you need to keep, eg bookmarks/history etc.
- and then reinstalling Chrome?

I had issues with Chrome not opening webpages or settings, and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, I did try it, and didn't work unfortunately.